# Program ignoring if elif statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm stumped, I have no idea why this is not working.  It just ignores everything except for the else statement.  No idea what could be causing this, help!

The program is just too simple to mess up, and yet, here it is, not working.

```
def main(): #the main function, where the program is held.
    print("Opening Account List now...\n")#flavor tx to add user context for the list of numbers to be displayed.

    infile = open('CHarge Accounts.txt', 'r')#opens the 'CHarge Accounts' text file in read-only mode,
                                            #and saves it to the variable 'infile'.
    numbers = infile.readlines()#The '.readlines()' command opens the text file stored in the 'infile'
                                #variable and and reads every single line of text in the file.
                                #It then saves the data that has been read to the variable 'numbers'.

    infile.close()#This closes the text file being within the 'infile' variable, preventing data from being los,
                  #and causing errors in the program

    index = 0#control value for the number of values to be inserted into the 'numbers' list.
             # 

    while index < len(numbers): #while the index value is less than the number of values within numbers.
                                #This means that as long as index is less than however many account numbers
                                #that are within the 'numbers' list, the loop will continue.

        numbers[index] = int(numbers[index])#While the loop runs, the values in the numbers index will be
                                            #converted to integer values 
        index += 1 #controlling value increments for every number read

    print (numbers, '\n')
    x = 0 #control value for the while loop.
    while x == 0: #Loop begins.
        accnumber = int(input("Please type in the account number you'd like to change, or type in -1 to exit."))

        if accnumber not in numbers and not -1:#Checks if account number is not in the saved txt file data, and
                                               #if the user has inputted the 'kill' value.

            print("The account number you have typed in is invalid.")#informs user data is invalid
        elif accnumber in numbers and not -1:#Checks if the account number is within the saved text file data, and
                                             #if the user has inputted the 'kill' value.

            print("The account number you have selected is valid.")#text informs user that data is valid
        elif accnumber == -1:#Checks if the account number value is -1
            print("Goodbye!")#Flavor for the user
            x = 1 #activates the control variable to break the loop
main()
```

Comment: Add spaces before your `# comments`. This is very hard to read, and breaks the syntax highlighter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if accnumber not in numbers and not -1:
                              # ^^^^^^
```

When evaluated as a truth-statement, 0 is `False` and any other integer is `True`. So `-1` is `True`, `not -1` is `False`, and `(anything) and not -1` is always `False`.

Therefore your `if` and `elif` clauses always get skipped.

Try

```
if accnumber not in numbers and accnumber != -1:
```

instead.

Also:

- your commenting is overdone to the point of obscuring your program. I presume this is some sort of class requirement, ie commenting *every line*?
- your use of `while` loops and index variables is very non-idiomatic and could be replaced by a list comprehension as follows:

.

```
def main():
    print("Opening Account List now...\n")

    with open('Charge Accounts.txt') as inf:
        numbers = [int(line) for line in inf]
    print(numbers, '\n')

    while True:
        accnumber = int(input("Please enter an account number (or -1 to exit): "))
        if accnumber == -1:
            print("Goodbye!")
            break
        elif accnumber not in numbers:
            print("The account number you have typed in is invalid.")
        else:
            print("The account number you have selected is valid.")

main()
```

Comment: I wasn't taught the 'with' and 'as' function, so I didn't use it.  How should I use it, if I want to?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit messy. When you are adding comments, please try to make it reader friendly. Also, spend more time on basic syntax!

```
def main():
    print("Opening Account List now...\n")

    infile = open('CHarge Accounts.txt', 'r')
    numbers = infile.readlines()

    infile.close()

    index = 0
    while index < len(numbers): 
        numbers[index] = int(numbers[index])

        index += 1

    print (numbers, '\n')
    x = 0 #control value for the while loop.
    while x == 0: 
        accnumber = int(input("Please type in the account number you'd like to change, or type in -1 to exit."))

        if (accnumber not in numbers) and (accnumber !=-1):
            print("The account number you have typed in is invalid.")

        elif (accnumber in numbers) and (accnumber !=-1):
            print("The account number you have selected is valid.")#text informs user that data is valid

        elif accnumber == -1:#Checks if the account number value is -1
            print("Goodbye!")#Flavor for the user
            x = 1 #activates the control variable to break the loop

main()
```